# Maximum recursion depth in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, recursion

What is the maximum recursion depth limitation of Objective-C ?

Comment: Yes. And I got an exception ...

Comment: Sorry, not an exception, but an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Of course you did, you had stack overflow.  The trick is to keep a running count of levels of recursion and NSLog it each time you call a function recursively.  The last NSLog before the crash is your answer

Comment: I would not NSLog it, just wait till it breaks and ask the debugger. With logging it should be minutes till it crashes, without seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no pre-set maximum recursion depth in Objective-C, or in most languages.

Furthermore a simple test where you recurse and count the times till you fault does not give you a realistic answer either, it will probably over-estimate the depth you can reach in a real program.

You can keep calling as long as there is sufficient space on the stack for the *frame* of the method/function you are calling. The frame includes various housekeeping information (usually fixed size), save registers (variable size) and the method/function's local variables (variable size) - so there is no single frame size.

If you want a rough approximation you could declare a function with the average number & types of local variables that occur in your code and count how many times you can recursively call it. That will give you an approximation *for the machine you're running on*.

Mac OS X itself imposes an upper limit to the stack size, you can find this for your kernel using `ulimit -s`. Also see this [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1419/_index.html)

Answer (score 2):

It will almost certainly depend on the size of the stack.